# How many check points in RHEL/CentOS to make sure no one have sudo/root access

Tags: linux, security, sudo, root, privileges

I want to make sure no one has `sudo` access or root access on some production servers. Some points I have also verified like:

1. `grep 'x:0:' /etc/passwd`
2. `grep root /etc/group`
3. `cat /etc/sudoers`
4. key in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file
5. some check points in `sshd.conf` like `PermitRootLogin no` etc.
6. `find / -perm -04000`
7. `getent passwd 0`
8. `getent group root wheel adm admin`

Did I forget/skip any?

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory, because it is included in the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```